# How can I write an SQLAlchemy Query with a Join and an Aggregate?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a table that has 3 columns: type, content and time (an integer). For each 'type', I want to select the entry with the greatest (most recent) 'time' integer and the corresponding data. How can I do this using SQLAlchemy and Python? I could do this using SQL by performing:

```
select
  c.type,
  c.time,
  b.data
from
  parts as b

inner join

  (select
    a.type,
    max(a.time) as time
  from parts as a
  group by a.type) as c

on

b.type = c.type and
b.time = c.time
```

But how can I accomplish this in SQLAlchemy?

The table mapping:

```
class Structure(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'structure'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    type = Column(Text)
    content = Column(Text)
    time = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, type, content):
        self.type = type
        self.content = content
        self.time = time.time()

    def serialise(self):
        return {"type" : self.type,
            "content" : self.content};
```

The attempted query:

```
    max = func.max(Structure.time).alias("time")
    c = DBSession.query(max)\
        .add_columns(Structure.type, Structure.time)\
        .group_by(Structure.type)\
        .subquery()
    c.alias("c")

    b = DBSession.query(Structure.content)\
        .add_columns(c.c.type, c.c.time)\
        .join(c, Structure.type == c.c.type)
```

Gives me:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (OperationalError) near "(": syntax
>   error u'SELECT structure.content AS structure_content, anon_1.type AS
>   anon_1_type, anon_1.t ime AS anon_1_time \nFROM structure JOIN (SELECT
>   time.max_1 AS max_1, structure.type AS type, structure.time AS time
>   \nFROM max(structure.time) AS time, structu re GROUP BY
>   structure.type) AS anon_1 ON structure.type = anon_1.type' ()

I'm essentially stabbing in the dark, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This can be accomplished using SQLAlchemy. Have you tried anything already? Do you have any table mappings defined?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hey Martijn, I posted this one on my way out of the office last night. I'll add some code to it once I've had a chance to have another look; thanks.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've added my work so far, no idea if I'm on the right track though.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the code below using sub-query:

```
subq = (session.query(
            Structure.type, 
            func.max(Structure.time).label("max_time")
        ).
        group_by(Structure.type)
        ).subquery()

qry = (session.query(Structure).
       join(subq, and_(Structure.type == subq.c.type, Structure.time == subq.c.max_time))
       )

print qry
```

producing SQL:

```
SELECT  structure.id AS structure_id, structure.type AS structure_type, structure.content AS structure_content, structure.time AS structure_time
FROM    structure 
JOIN    (SELECT structure.type AS type, max(structure.time) AS max_time
         FROM structure GROUP BY structure.type) AS anon_1 
    ON  structure.type = anon_1.type 
    AND structure.time = anon_1.max_time
```

Comment: Winner! Thanks for your help, you've cleared up my main question as well as a few smaller questions (such as 'how do I join on multiple column?'), really appreciate your help; thanks.